# Issue Running Game Engine in Android Using Threads

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, game-engine, runnable

I am currently working on building a game (an RPG) for Android from scratch and am having issues integrating the logic using Android.

I have a working version of the game engine I am working on in a separate Java program in Eclipse. However, when I try to run the engine in Android (built using Android Studio), I get caught up in Android's quirks and it does not run properly.

The issue lies in the fact that Android is event driven and requires calculations to be diverted to a worker thread. Unfortunately, this means I have to use special methods to have visual response using Android's UI. (I've learned that this is not thread safe.) I had no issues to compare this with in the "vanilla" version because it is very straight forward and instead runs on print statements and scanners.

So I start the engine from a Runnable (from the Activity) like so:

```
 engine = new TestEngine(this);

    setButtonsInvisible();

    runnable = new EngineRunnable(this, engine);
    Log.i("Thread","Runnable Created");
    thread = new Thread(runnable);
    Log.i("Thread", "Thread created");
    thread.start();
    Log.i("Thread","Thread Started");
```

EngineRunnable is another class that holds information for that specific instance of the TestEngine (the units that are attacking) and calls the TestEngine.

The SetButtonsVisible() Method (also in the Activity) makes four programatically defined buttons appear on Screen using RunOnUIThread to set its visibility so the buttons can be pressed. I have a SetButtonsInvisible() method to set these same buttons to View.INVISIBLE and View.GONE.

The runnable eventually calls this "Battle" method, which is in a GameEngine class

```
public void battle(BattleUnit unitA, BattleUnit unitB) {
    unitA.setName("Player 1");
    unitB.setName("Player 2");
    activity.setTVText(unitA.getName() + " starts at " + unitA.getLocX() + " , " + unitA.getLocY() + " .");
    activity.setTVText(unitB.getName() + " starts at " + unitB.getLocX() + " , " + unitB.getLocY() + " .");
    Log.i("Sequence","1");
    while (unitA.isActive() && unitB.isActive()) {
        decideTurn(unitA, unitB);
    }
    declareWinner(unitA, unitB);

}
```

And the issue comes into play in these called methods

```
public void decideTurn (BattleUnit unit1, BattleUnit unit2){
    //Unit 1 is faster and moves first
    if(unit1.getSpeed() >= unit2.getSpeed() && unit1.hasMoved() == false){
        activity.setTVText(unit1.getName()+"'s turn!");
        action(unit1, unit2);
        Log.i("Sequence", "2");
    }
    //Unit 2 is faster and moves first OR Unit 1 is faster and Unit 2 moves second
    else if (unit2.hasMoved() == false){
        activity.setTVText(unit2.getName()+"'s turn!");
        action(unit2, unit1);
        Log.i("Sequence", "2");
    }
    //Unit 2 is faster and Unit 1 moves second
    else if (unit2.hasMoved() == true && unit1.hasMoved() == false) {
        activity.setTVText(unit1.getName() + "'s turn!");
        action(unit1, unit2);
        Log.i("Sequence","2");}
    //Both units moved
    else{
        unit1.newTurn();
        unit2.newTurn();
        Log.i("Sequence", "New Turn");
    }
}
```

Which calls the action method here:

```
private void action(BattleUnit unit1, BattleUnit unit2){
    activity.activateButtons(unit1, unit2, 1);
    Log.i("Sequence", "3");
}
```

And this is the method that changes the UI. I move the last method to a TextView up higher on the screen. There are four of these. The bottom of the four is placed as the "current" message like so:

```
public synchronized void setTVText (CharSequence charSequence){

    final CharSequence sequence = charSequence;

    //textHandler = new Handler();
    //textHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tv1.setText(tv2.getText());
                tv2.setText(tv3.getText());
                tv3.setText(tv4.getText());
                tv4.setText(sequence);
            }
        });
}
```

So when I test the program on my phone, no matter what buttons are used, the program prints out what Player's Turn it is. In my example, it is always Player 2. So it will print it four times.

I have the code logged as shown. When I run the code, the logs have the sequence alternating between 2 and 3 (or bouncing between deciding the turn and turning the buttons on that will show the action). Additionally, when I go to change the buttons by choosing to move (like how I change the TextViews), the program lags behind (I assume it must either override the change with what the engine starts with or the program is doing so many alterations between point 2 and 3 that it never reaches the button press)

I don't understand at all why. I'm relatively new at Android development, especially multithreading. Is it calling the engine more than once? Or is it the nature of my code with the while statement that keeps the game going?

Any help or advice at all would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try implementing callback/interface? Since an action trigger a response, you create a interface and parse it to the engine which it can callback to the main activity and update the activity UI.

Interface/Callback

```
public interface EngineCallback {

       void actionComplete();
       void changePlayerTurnTV(String text);
       void doAction(BattleUnit unit1, BattleUnit unit2);

}
```

In your game activity implement this interface, and then pass the interface to your engine.

Engine Example

```
public class GameEngine {

private mEngineCallback;

public GameEngine(EngineCallback callback) {
       mEngineCallback = callback;
}

public void decideTurn (BattleUnit unit1, BattleUnit unit2){
    //Unit 1 is faster and moves first
    if(unit1.getSpeed() >= unit2.getSpeed() && unit1.hasMoved() == false){
        mEngineCallback.changePlayerTurnTV(unit1.getName()+"'s turn!");
        action(unit1, unit2);
        Log.i("Sequence", "2");
    }
    //Unit 2 is faster and moves first OR Unit 1 is faster and Unit 2 moves second
    else if (unit2.hasMoved() == false){
        mEngineCallback.changePlayerTurnTV(unit2.getName()+"'s turn!");
        action(unit2, unit1);
        Log.i("Sequence", "2");
    }
    //Unit 2 is faster and Unit 1 moves second
    else if (unit2.hasMoved() == true && unit1.hasMoved() == false) {
        mEngineCallback.changePlayerTurnTV(unit1.getName() + "'s turn!");
        action(unit1, unit2);
        Log.i("Sequence","2");}
    //Both units moved
    else{
        unit1.newTurn();
        unit2.newTurn();
        Log.i("Sequence", "New Turn");
    }
}

private void action(BattleUnit unit1, BattleUnit unit2){
     mEngineCallback.doAction(unit1, unit2);
}

public void performExampleAction() {
     // proccessing code
     // processing code
     mEngineCallback.actionComplete();
}

}
```

GameActivity

```
public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements EngineCallback {

...

@Override
public void actionComplete() {
// update UI code
}

@Override
public void changePlayerTurnTV(String text) {
tv1.setText(tv2.getText());
tv2.setText(tv3.getText());
tv3.setText(tv4.getText());
tv4.setText(text);
}

@Override
public void doAction(BattleUnit unit1, BattleUnit unit2) {
       activateButtons(unit1, unit2, 1);
}
}
```

Always use callback/interface when a action will trigger a response and always separate the business layer with the presentation layer.

**EDITED: refactoring part of your code into the implementation**

Comment: I haven't tried this yet. Thank you very much for the suggestion.
Unfortunately, I'll have trouble implementing it because Java doesn't support multiple inheritances. (I already have View.OnClickListener implemented in the activity to handle button clicks.)

Comment: Activity to handle button click, but button click trigger a function in the GameEngine, so GameEngine will do the processing and notify the activity that the processing is done, so the activity can do the updating of ui.

Comment: To be honest, I'm confused by what you mean. Are you saying to call this interface after I finish doing any of the actions (whose calculations are set up in individual methods) so it will only update the UI when calculations are finished? And handle button clicking in the activity instead of just putting View.OnClickListener as an implementation at the start of the program?

Will this solve my problem by forcing the UI to wait? I'm just also concerned by the log results going back and forth between areas of my code (that don't call each other backwards) instead of just moving forward normally.

Comment: What do you mean by force UI to wait, also what you mean by "handle button clicking in the activity instead of just putting View.OnClickListener as an implementation at the start of the program"? Yes, you do the calculation with the game engine and send it to the UI using the interface. I'm assuming that all the methods listed above except for the setTVText are implemented within the TestEngine class.

Comment: I meant that the UI seems to update so quickly that it skips frames I want the user to see. And by that I mean I currently create the class saying it implements View.OnClickListener. The solution you're suggesting would replace that with the Callback/Interface, so I would have to create the listener for the buttons individually in the activity. And thank you for answering. I was double checking. The only of the above, aside from the setTVText is the declaration of a thread using an instance of my runnable, which is in the activity also. Should I move that to the engine itself too?

Comment: Have you tested and it skips frames? What is the flow of your game?

Comment: Sorry for the belated answer. I have tested, but it skips things it should show. I haven't checked lately to see if it skipped frames specifically. By method name, it flows like this with an arrow meaning it calls something. Activity (OnCreate)->Creates Thread from Runnable->Battle->DecideTurn->Action->(One of the Actions)->Battle->DecideTurn....(Battle Ends; One Unit "Defeated")->DeclareWinner.